# Finding the roots of a polynomial

Tags: haskell, algebra, polynomials

Given a polynomial of degree n, how can I reliably find all values of x where y = 0.

I'm currently using the [`Math.Polynomial`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polynomial-0.7.3/docs/Math-Polynomial.html) library, which doesn't seem to have this function built in. However, I could be missing something here, it seems like this would be a widely used function.

Thanks

Comment: `separateRoots` *should* get you most of the way there, but it doesn't seem to work correctly.  E.g. `separateRoots BE [1,0,-1]` fails to separate.

Comment: Note that once *n* is greater than 5, there is no algebraic exact way to find the roots: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Interesting. I was sure this theorem was originally due to Galois.

Comment: Well the theorem has been proved in 1824, at that moment, Galois was 13 years old. Although Galois was very young when he died (as a result of a love affair and in a duel if I recall correctly), but as far as I know, he did not wrote that theorem when he was 13.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No general way, there however exceptions, x^5  = 1 has only roots which can be algebraically found for example.

Comment: @luqui thats what I was thinking, but wasn't sure if that was expected behavior or not. I may file a bug report.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I read somewhere (don't remember where) that Abel proved the case degree=5 only (this contradicts Wikipedia), while Galois proved the case higher than 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Polynomial.Roots` module of the [`dsp` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dsp-0.2.4/docs/Polynomial-Roots.html). It deals with complex values (complex coefficients and complex roots).

For instance, to solve `1+2x+2x²=0`:

```
Prelude> import Polynomial.Roots 
Prelude Polynomial.Roots> roots 1e-16 1000 [1,2,2]
[(-0.5) :+ (-0.5),(-0.5) :+ 0.5]
```

As a sanity check, R gives the same result:

```
> polyroot(c(1,2,2))
[1] -0.5+0.5i -0.5-0.5i
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using an external SMT solver, you can use the SBV package:

```
Prelude Data.SBV> allSat $ \x -> 2*x^3-19*x^2+15*x+72 .== (0::SReal)
Solution #1:
  s0 = 3.0 :: Real
Solution #2:
  s0 = 8.0 :: Real
Solution #3:
  s0 = -1.5 :: Real
Found 3 different solutions.
```

You are guaranteed that the roots will be precise, i.e., no rounding error will happen. The `Real` type corresponds to infinitely precise algebraic reals. If the result cannot be printed in a finite form, it'll be written as the root of a simple equation and will be expanded to the current print precision:

```
Prelude Data.SBV> allSat $ \x -> x^2-2 .== (0::SReal)
Solution #1:
  s0 = root(1, x^2 = 2) = -1.414213562373095... :: Real
Solution #2:
  s0 = root(2, x^2 = 2) = 1.414213562373095... :: Real
Found 2 different solutions.
```

The number of digits can be arbitrarily long and is configurable:

```
Prelude Data.SBV> allSatWith z3{printRealPrec=20} $ \x -> x^2-2 .== (0::SReal)
Solution #1:
  s0 = root(1, x^2 = 2) = -1.4142135623730950488... :: Real
Solution #2:
  s0 = root(2, x^2 = 2) = 1.4142135623730950488... :: Real
Found 2 different solutions.
```

Note that SMT solvers will only get you real-roots; no complex solutions will be found:

```
Prelude Data.SBV> allSat $ \x -> x^2+1 .== (0::SReal)
No solutions found.
```

If only some roots are real, those will be found:

```
Prelude Data.SBV> allSat $ \x -> x^3+2*x-1 .== (0::SReal)
Solution #1:
  s0 = root(1, x^3+2x = 1) = 0.4533976515164037... :: Real
This is the only solution.
```

PS. To make this all work, do not forget to first install Z3 on your machine. You can get a recent copy from https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases